# cannot convert from 'string' to 'SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.EmailAddress'

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am trying to build some basic email functionality within a c# asp.net application. My skills are limited and I am learning.

I am trying to send a list of email addresses to the application. I get the following error when creating the list:

cannot convert from 'string' to 'SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.EmailAddress'

I can see that the list reader is bringing the email address column as a string and I need to convert this to the [SendGrid.Helpers.Mail.EmailAddress] but I have no idea how to do this.

```
protected async void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            // Prepare the email message info model
            var apiKey = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGrid_API_Key"];
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var com = new SqlConnection("Myconn");
            com.Open();
            string qry = "SELECT EmailAddress FROM MyTable";
            var con = new SqlCommand(qry, com);

            //var recipients = new List<EmailAddress>{
            //new EmailAddress("Recipient1@test.co.uk", "User 1"),
            //new EmailAddress("Recipient2@test.co.uk", "User 2") };

            List<EmailAddress> columnData = new List<EmailAddress>();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(qry, com))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader bb = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (bb.Read())
                    {
                        columnData.Add(bb.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
            }
            var msg = new SendGridMessage();

            msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("Sender@azure.com", "Me"));


            var recipients3 = columnData;
            msg.AddTos(recipients3);

            msg.SetSubject("Without ttttt");

            msg.AddContent(MimeType.Text, "Dear Sir or Madam,!");
            msg.AddContent(MimeType.Html, "<p>Dear Sir or Madam,!</p>");

            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the syntex is :myMessage.From = new EmailAddress("you@youremail.com", "First Last");

Comment: `columnData.Add(new EmailAddress(bb.GetString(0)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you are trying to add a String into a list of email addresses:

```
  while (bb.Read())
  {
      columnData.Add(bb.GetString(0)); //error is here.
  }
```

What you need to to is create a new object EmailAddress - with your retrieve string as parameter for the EmailAddress constructor:

```
while (bb.Read())
{
    columnData.Add(new EmailAddress(bb.GetString(0)));
}
```

Edit:

If you have another field in myTable then change your query to:

```
string qry = "SELECT EmailAddress, Car FROM MyTable";
```

Create a list to hold the car values:

I have assumed the Car column is a string

```
var columnDataCar = new List<string>();
```

Retrive the values:

```
while (bb.Read())
{
 columnData.Add(new EmailAddress(bb.GetString(0)));
 columnDataCar.Add(bb.GetString(1);
}
```

Now columnDataCar holds the data for the Car field.

```
foreach(var item in columnDataCar)
{
 msg.AddContent(MimeType.Text, item);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much gents. This is perfect. Works exactly how I want.

Comment: If I had an additional field in my data table e.g. Car. Is there a way that I could pull that column from the list and include in the email message text?